# How do I check certain values in a boolean array?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

Exactly as the title says, how do I check only certain values in a boolean array. My array is 11 values long, and I want to check only certain values of the array. So if I wanted to check if any of values 0-5 are false how would I go about doing that? Here is what I have so far for doing that:

```
    boolean checkFirst : seats[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: wheres the code to determine whats going wrong?

Comment: No, `boolean checkFirst : seats[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];` will not compile`. Are you sure you used the right language tag?

Comment: I just want to know how to check only certain values in a boolean array. What I am trying to do is determine if any one of those six values are false. Does that help (also that is the only code where an error is occuring)?

Comment: That is not valid Java syntax.

Comment: I know because I am getting a syntax error, what is the correct way of checking if any of a certain value(s) is false or not?

Comment: @person3122 Java doesn't have such a function. You can write one, but it'll take three arguments (the array, the start and the end).

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop to inspect the values.  Use a conditional (if-statement) inside the loop to decide whether to inspect any given value.  It could be a parallel array, or a list.  If it is a list, then alternatively you could simply pop or read the index from the list and use that as the index into the boolean array.  There are many ways to solve this.

If it is just seats on an airplane (for example), then there is no efficiency to gain by a sophisticated scheme.

Program for clarity.  Write pseudo-code first, decide on data structures, and then replace pseudo-code gradually with program code and then with compilable code and then with working code.